# Saving email as PDF

Tags: apex, trigger

Sending an email from a process builder when a condition is true. How can I save the email as PDF to a custom object?

Comment: If you using a VF template for send the email, then probably you could write a custom implementation to save the VF as PDF.

Comment: I'm sending an email through process builder as Email Alerts and doing other things like creating a task etc

Comment: You'd likely need to use a visualforce page template that used `renderAsPdf` in the Apex:Page definition or something along those lines.

Comment: Can I use an action type 'apex' in the process builder?

Comment: you could but still you will a VF template. Take a look at this link,https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_render_in_apex.htm